# Require more `TH Sarabunit๙` font for Google docs, sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

File - Language - ไทย  has been set

[image: th sarabunit psk]

But still just `TH SarabunPSK` doesn't fit our need enough, we want more `TH Sarabunit๙` font.

Google fonts doesn't have `TH SarabunPSK` either but still be able to use, so I require for `TH Sarabunit๙` font as well.

The font I require here will help us with Thai numbers such as autofill. The only `TH SarabunPSK` font isn't able to do that.

[image: Google-Sheets]

it directly changes the number display to Thai numbers.

We need either,

- so if we want the number `0123456789` we use `TH SarabunPSK`.
- if we want Thai numbers `๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙` we just need to change the font to `TH Sarabunit๙`, all the other characters are the same.

When we type number we type `0123456789` not symbols like `๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙` because the computer doesn't understand them as numbers.

I currently MANUALLY type the Thai number one by one, which is too much unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2):

you can search fonts over:

https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=%E0%B9%90%E0%B9%91%E0%B9%92%E0%B9%93%E0%B9%94%E0%B9%95%E0%B9%96%E0%B9%97%E0%B9%98%E0%B9%99%200123456789&preview.text_type=custom

and see the compatibility:

[image]

---

### update

the easiest way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, 
 0, "๐"), 1, "๑"), 2, "๒"), 3, "๓"), 4, "๔"), 
 5, "๕"), 6, "๖"), 7, "๗"), 8, "๘"), 9, "๙"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want that [https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=0123456789&preview.text_type=custom&subset=thai](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=0123456789&preview.text_type=custom&subset=thai) the result should be `๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙`

Comment: @zummon in that case I can suggest a formula that will convert 123 into ๑๒๓. let me know if you are interested in such solution

Comment: I was searching but too complicated solutions I found. Let's see your solution, I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @zummon answer updated